# Не работатет error-handler в express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

имеется приложение на typescript с использованием typescript. Я пытаюсь обработать ошибки, но вместо json на выходе получаю html. Error-handler так же должен коректно выводить ошибки созданые mongo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.ts

```
import express, { Express, NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import connectDB = require('./db/connect-db');
import { apiRouter } from './routes';
import cors from 'cors';
import { errorHandler } from './middleware/error-handler';
import createError from 'http-errors';

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

try {
  connectDB();
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log('\x1b[31m%s', String('-').repeat(50));
    console.log(err.status);
    console.log(`Message: ${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Path: ${req.path}`);
    console.log('\x1b[31m%s', String('-').repeat(50));

    res
      .status(err?.status || 500)
      .json({ message: err.message, path: req.path, key: err.code, ...err });
  });
  app.use('/api', apiRouter);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

controllers.ts

```
import User from '../db/models/User';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import createError from 'http-errors';

export const register = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, gender, password, birthday } = req.body;
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (existingUser)
      createError({ code: 400, message: 'Username already exists' });
    const hashedPass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    const user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      gender,
      password: hashedPass,
      birthday,
    });
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

export const login = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!password || !email) {
      throw createHttpError(400, {
        message: 'Please provide both email and password',
        code: 'login - missing email or password',
      });
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      throw createHttpError(404, {
        message: 'Cannot find user with provided email',
        code: 'login - missing user with provided email',
      });
    }

    const result = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

    if (!result) {
      throw createHttpError(401, {
        message: 'Invalid email password pair',
        code: 'login - invalid credentials pair',
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

export const list = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const list = await User.find();
    res.status(200).json(list);
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```

Заголовки

```
{
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NWM5ZGU1NDMzZTFkOGFkYmE2NGZmZDYiLCJuYW1lIjoiVGVzdCBVc2VyNyIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdDdAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZGF0ZSI6IjIwMjQtMDItMTJUMDk6MjA6MzguMTUyWiIsImlhdCI6MTcwNzcyOTYzOH0.QbxR12psHSnonExphH-yqUasmdxstlB8hFTBkddrtZc',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.36.1',
  accept: '*/*',
  'postman-token': '1e119acc-e868-40f2-adb3-f4688f4e55fa',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
}
```

Comment: на скриншоте видна ошибка Mongo - что именно не так с этим ответом?

Comment: @Grundy Ошибка должна быть в фотмате json, но она выводится в html.

Comment: какие заголовки шлются в запросе? если в нем есть `accept` то скорее всего надо проверять как там указано `application/json` а не просто `json` - если нет - то либо убрать проверку ` if (req.accepts('json')) {` и всегда отдавать json - либо добавить заголовок в запрос

Comment: @Grundy добавил заголовки в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy насколько я понял, ошибка просто не попадает в next(), я поменял обработчик на заведомо рабочий, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#:~:text=You%20define%20error%2Dhandling%20middleware%20last%2C%20after%20other

Comment: По ссылке выше указано что обработчик ошибки должен быть последним в определении `use` а у тебя после него добавляется `route` еще

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, в этом как раз и была ошибка

Comment: @krokozyablik, плз, пометьте ответ принятым, он пригодится для базы знаний

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны объявить обработчик ошибок в последнюю очередь, он должен быть последним в определении - после других `app.use()` и router-ов.

Пример:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

/* Errors handler */
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // logic
});
```

Документация: [writing error handlers](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers)